# After all the transients have settled down what would be the output voltage

Tags: vlsi, nmos, pmos

[image]

Vo(0)=5 , what is Vo(infinity)
Can you please explain to me how i can get the answer.

Comment: Note that after all transients have died down, the transistors have no DC connection to ground. 4V and 1V are applied to insulated gates which hardly conduct any current. All that stands between +5V and your multimeter probe at Vo is the two transistor channels connected in series.

Answer (score 1):

If \$V_{o}(0)=5V\$, it means the cap is charged.

Imagine both transistors were in conduction: nothing would happen, because the cap and the voltage supply are at the same potential.

Now imagine the transistors were off: nothing would happen, because the cap has nowhere to discharge.

In both cases, \$V_{o}(\infty)=5V\$

However, infinity is a long time, and real caps self discharge over time, plus mosfets have gate leakage, but I suspect this is beyond the scope of the exercise.

By the way, you should use a mosfet symbol that differentiates between source and drain, at least when it is not obvious.  Also, try Ctrl-M to open CircuitLab and draw the circuit more clearly than by hand.